# Android Nougat device not sending locations to the server in doze off mode

Tags: android, location, android-7.0-nougat, android-doze

I am designing an app in which I need to send locations periodically to the server. But due to the doze off feature, the device stops sending locations after sometime. Is there a workaround that can be done to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.